# checkstyle_error of unused @param tag

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

i am getting this check_style error

```
"Unused @param tag for &apos;Resource&apos;."
```

and  `@param tag for &apos;rec&apos`

for

```
/**
     * @param Resource rec
     */
    public Utility(final Resource rec) {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = rec.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can anyone tell me, what is the reason for this error.

Thanks

Comment: I answered that already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694983/how-to-resolve-checkstyle-error-xml-errors

Comment: @michael667, i am stil getting Expected @ param tag for &apos;rec&apos;   even if i used @ param rec

Comment: Remove the space between _@_ and _param_, and add some description, e.g. `@param rec a resource`

Comment: space is not there, is it necessary to add comment to remove this error.

Comment: So how do you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

To solve, replace

`@param Resource rec`

by

`@param rec`

**Edit**

Because otherwise it thinks `Resource` is the parameter and `rec` is the description.

Comment: and what about Expected @param tag for &apos;rec&apos for the same, even if i used @ param rec now

Comment: As indicated by @michael667, use `@param rec` not `@ param rec`.